# copyTo in AppScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm very new to Javascript and Apps Script I'm looking to create a function that updates another sheet based on the date in a specific range of the active sheet. I run and there are no errors but it is not transferring the values from the active sheet to the named sheet "2022 YTD".

Please help me see what I'm not seeing.

```
function updateYTD() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var copyName = sheet.getSheetName

  if (copyName == "January") {
    sheet.getRange("C2:D32").copyTo(ss.getSheetByName("2022 YTD").getRange("C2"),{contentsOnly:true});
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about modifying `var copyName = sheet.getSheetName` to `var copyName = sheet.getSheetName()`, and test it again? In order to run the function, please add `()`. I thought that the reason of your issue is due to this.

Comment: Yup that was it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function updateYTD() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");
  if (sheet) {
    sheet.getRange("C2:D32").copyTo(ss.getSheetByName("2022 YTD").getRange("C2"),{contentsOnly:true});
  }
}
```